# Why would you use 'extern "C++"'?

Tags: c++, c

In this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0603949d(VS.80).aspx) the keyword extern can be followed by "C" or "C++".  Why would you use 'extern "C++"'?  Is it practical?

Comment: good question though, welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Comment: The article is now at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/extern-cpp?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 125, accepted):

The language permits:

```
extern "C" {
  #include "foo.h"
}
```

What if foo.h contains something which requires C++ linkage?

```
    void f_plain(const char *);
    extern "C++" void f_fancy(const std::string &);
```

That's how you keep the linker happy.

Comment: I do not understand the downvotes.  This is a use case where extern C++ is required, and it is legal.

Comment: i don't understand it either. it's a valid use of extern "C++"

Comment: Not only is it valid, I've seen it in use in the wild (it was my 'aha' moment for it).  Take a look at winnt.h.

Comment: Don't worry; I voted it up because of the downvotes when I otherwise wouldn't have. Not because it doesn't deserve to be voted up, but simply because I wouldn't have thought to otherwise.

Answer (score 39):

There is no real reason to use `extern "C++"`.  It merely make explicit the linkage that is the implicit default.  If you have a class where some members have extern "C" linkage, you may wish the explicit state that the others are extern "C++".

Note that the C++ Standard defines syntactically `extern "anystring"`.  It only give formal meanings to `extern "C"` and `extern "C++"`.  A compiler vendor is free to define `extern "Pascal"` or even `extern "COM+"` if they like.

Comment: This is really the perfect answer to the question. I would give more votes if I could.

Comment: You use it when you need to override some other linkage specification in a surrounding scope.

Comment: I wish compilers supported `extern "Haskell"`.

Answer (score 26):

I'm not sure why you would need to do it, but according to [this](http://www.astro.louisville.edu/moore/software/xmccd/archive/xmccd-4.2.1/xmccd-4.2.1/docs/cpp/mixing_c_and_cpp.txt) article from Sun, you can use extern "C++" inside a block of extern "C" to specify certain functions in a group of "C" functions have the native C++ linkage.

```
extern "C" {
    void f();             // C linkage
    extern "C++" {
        void g();         // C++ linkage
        extern "C" void h(); // C linkage
        void g2();        // C++ linkage
    }
    extern "C++" void k();// C++ linkage
    void m();             // C linkage
}
```

Comment: This is probably to deal with situations where a header is included within one of the extern sections.

Answer (score 6):

Two guesses:

- If you are in a `extern "C"` block, you can get C++ language linkage again by specifying a nested `extern "C++"`.
- It reserves `C++` linkage, because it's the document defining C++. Who is in a better position for defining `C++` language linkage than it itself. It also provides for completeness. Same deal as with `signed/unsigned`.

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592160/static-vs-extern-c/592205#592205) that explains `extern "LanguageName"` (i.e GCC has `extern "Java"`) aswell.

Answer (score 4):

Extern "C" is answered by many. The use case for extern "C++" is when calling C++ library function in a C function. The sub-use case, that is relevant, is when linking a C++ library with a C source code with main function. Check this [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C++#Linking_C_and_C.2B.2B_code) for more details:

Answer (score 3):

C and C++ use different [name mangling rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).  Essentially, extern "C" tells the C++ compiler to name the function as C would name it.

Comment: Actually, name mangling is purely an implementation detail.  The languages themselves have no mangling "rules" at all. Various compilers have different ways handling function overloading.  Name mangling is just one popular method.

Answer (score 1):

This specify which link convention to use. Most languages know how to link with a "C" style function.

You need this in two cases :

- A C - or other languages for that matter- program calling a function written in C++
- A C++ program calling a function written in C

Example :

```
// declared in function.h
void f1(void);
```

Your C code - actually other languages are able to link with C function - will not be able to link to it because the name in the object table will use C++ convention.

If you write

```
extern "C" void f1(void);
```

Now the linking works because it uses C convention.

Answer (score 1):

The #1 reason I use extern "C" is to avoid C++'s name mangling rules.  This is very important if you are working in a .Net language and want to PInvoke into a particular native function.  The only way to do this is with name mangling disabled.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second question, "is it practical?":

It is practical, and practically unavoidable, in standard headers like `<cmath>`.

Imagine a header-only library X.h, written in a common subset of C++ and C, and intended to be used from both languages. For the benefit of C++ users, X.h includes `<cmath>`, not `<math.h>`. This would not work for C users though, hadn't the authors of `<cmath>` sandwiched everything in `extern "C++" {` ... `}`.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer is that you can use extern C to tell the compiler not to use name-mangling. This means you can link together bits of C and C++ code in the same project.

Comment: But, the question body also asks the question that James answered.

Comment: extern "c" is easily googled, but extern "c++" is an interesting question, will take it back if I'm wrong!

Comment: It seemed to me to be a question about why you would use either. There are better answers now so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score -2):

extern "C" is used to say that a C++ function should have C linkage. What this means is implementation dependant, but normally it turns off C++ name-mangling (and so overloading and strict type checking). You use it when you have a C++ function you want to be called from C code:

```
extern "C" void Foo();   // can be called easily from C
```

As for extern "C++", I've never seen it in real code, though the C++ Standard allows it. I guess it is a no-op.

Comment: Actually, it's mostly used for the reverse: calling a C function from C++ code.  If you call `printf` in your C++ code, the link needs to know that it's in the library as `printf` and not `printf_#$D%G^_&_^`