# Qt and VS C++ dll function returning value

Tags: c++, string, qt, dll, wstring

I'm trying to get std::string/std::wstring returned value from connected DLL in Qt and I having problem with this.

code from DLL:

```
using namespace std;
extern "C++" __declspec(dllexport) string test()
{
    return "Passed!";
}
```

code in my Qt application (Qt Creator):

```
typedef std::string (*Test)();
QLibrary *lib = new QLibrary("dllname");
lib->load();
.... dll load check ....
Test test = (Test) lib->resolve("test");
std::string s = test();
QString name = QString::fromStdString(s);
```

In result "name" variable will have "H" insted of "Passed!"
What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you linking dynamically to the same runtime?

Comment: Yes, linking in Qt Ctreator, dll compiled in VS2010

Comment: Your Qt app needs to link against MSVC runtime too. Oh, and there's no extern "C++".

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes there is, though being the default it is not needed (unless you're trying to override another linkage): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610934/why-would-you-use-extern-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your comments, I've made it:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int test(wchar_t* out)
{
    wcscpy_s(out, MAX_PATH, L"Passed!"); // I'm using sys paths in my app, 
                                           // so MAX_PATH is ok for me
    return 0;
}
```

Qt side:

```
typedef int (*Test)(wchar_t*);
QLibrary *lib = new QLibrary("dllname");
lib->load();
.... dll load check ....
Test test = (Test) lib->resolve("test");
wchar_t s[MAX_PATH];
test(s);
QString name = QString::fromWCharArray(s);
```

Variable "name" now should be "Passed!"

In QLibrary class reference says about support only

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
```

directive.

**UPDATED** Thanks @MSalters

Comment: I think you're mistaken on the assumption. You _can_ use `std::string` in `extern "C"` functions.

Comment: I was confused by compiler errors and I did wrong assumption. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `extern "C++"` functions have their name mangled. This allows overloading. `extern "C"` functions cannot be overloaded.

`QLibrary` cannot deal with overloading, nor with name mangling. It therefore needs `extern "C"` functions. However, these *may* still use C++ types.

If you fail, you will get Undefined Behavior. You're unlucky, it would have been better if it would just have crashed.