# Is `extern "C"` a part of the type of a function?

Tags: c++, c, c++11, calling-convention

I don't see any comment in the standard except linkage related things.

Though the standard doesn't say anything about calling convention,  the calling conventions might be different between C and C++ in the real world, so I expected that the types of a C function and a C++ function are different. But it seems not, especially in GCC.

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

extern "C" {
  int c_func(int);
}

int cpp_func(int);

static_assert(!std::is_same<decltype(c_func), decltype(cpp_func)>::value,
              "It should not be the same type");
```

`static_assert` fails since GCC considers those functions have the same type.

- Is `extern "C"` a part of the type of a function?
- How do I check if a function uses C calling convention or C++ calling convention?

Comment: C++ supports e.g. function overloading. Two functions with different argument types but same name - it cannot be done with C linking because function name needs to be mangled to remain unique.

Comment: @keltar Yes, you're right, and that's not what I'm asking here. It's about the calling convention, not name mangling. Every docs, Q/A about `extern "c"` I found on the internet says about name mangling but not the calling convention.

Comment: Since it cannot be used on methods (and hence can't affect thiscall) - yes, it should only disable mangling without modifying convention, unless explicitly specified otherwise (e.g. with `__attribute__` compiler-specific command). Both types you comparing are `int (*)(int)`.

Comment: Maybe a little less obscure - C++ already uses the same convention as C for ordinary functions (it isn't the case with methods, however), so there is nothing to change here. However, C convention changes with ABI you use, so it would be different between 32bit, 64bit system V, 64bit windows, etc., for both C and C++.

Comment: @keltar most C++ compilers mangle everything, ordinary functions included, unless told not to.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26174510/

Comment: @ChrisStratton I don't even think 'most', because they have to mangle; that's exactly what I've told in first comment.

Comment: @keltar Mangling isn't the only thing involved.  I've used compilers where the calling conventions were different for C and for C++.

Comment: @JamesKanze unlikely but possible. Hard to maintain multiple ABIs without much of a reason. Would like to know what compiler is that, though.

Comment: @keltar Zortech.  For MS-DOS under Windows.  There are very good reasons for doing so on Intel (16 and 32 bit) architecture.  And I don't see any real problem with regards to multiple ABIs either.

Comment: extern is for linkage and scope. It is not for type.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The standard makes it clear that *language linkage* is indeed a property of a function *type* itself:

> All function types, function names with external linkage, and variable names with external linkage have a
>   *language linkage.*

In case that wasn't clear enough, there's a note (emphasis mine) that makes the intended meaning unambiguous:

> *[ Note:* Because the **language linkage is part of a function type,** when indirecting through a pointer to C
>   function, the function to which the resulting lvalue refers is considered a C function. — *end note ]*

Furthermore,

> Two function types with different language
>    linkages are distinct types even if they are otherwise identical.

So the answer to your first question is:

- **Yes**, `extern "C"` is part of the type of a function.

However, most compilers fail to distinguish between the types of functions with C and C++ language linkage. This is for example a long-standing bug in GCC (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=2316; see list of duplicates). I didn't read the entire thread carefully, but it appears that a lot of existing code would break if GCC started enforcing the rule that they really are different types. This is presumably also why other compilers also fail to conform to the standard.

Given that, the answer to your second question would seem to be:

- There is probably no portable way to perform this check at compile time. Of course after translation you can always go in and look at the object file and see whether the name is mangled or not.

But *in theory*, your static assertion is supposed to work the way you think it should. That just isn't the case in practice.

**Addendum:**

If my understanding of the standard is correct, then for example the following function template

```
template <typename R, typename... A>
void f(R(*)(A...));
```

cannot be instantiated to produce a function that would accept a pointer to a function with C language linkage as an argument, since the type `R(*)(A...)` is "pointer to function **with C++ language linkage** taking arguments of types `A...` and returning `R`".

If compilers really worked like this, it's easy to see how you could generically determine whether a function has C or C++ language linkage.

But this example should also make it clear how badly existing code would break if compilers really worked this way.