# What does PFYvv stands for? (not PFvv!)

Tags: c++, arm, name-mangling, armcc

I'm trying to link a symbol's file with mangled generated ones from the header.
(matching ROM located functions to the RAM ones.)

In the .sym I have a function with "**PFvv**" parameter, 
normally demangled to -> VOID (fn*)(VOID).

The compiler is instead producing the following output as parameter: **PFYvv**

Result: the linker doesn't link.

**Questions**:

What does the Y stands for?
Is there a reference doc for ARM mangling?

.sym mangled name:

```
_ZN10CCasd15lolEP13strPcPFvvEhPvm
```

compiler generated name:

```
_ZN10CCasd15lolEP13strPcPFYvvEhPvm
```

.h definition

```
class CCasd{
    static int lol(in_str*h, char* name, void(*fn)(void), unsigned char p, void *s, unsigned long l);
};
```

**POST-ANSWER CODE**:

Here is how you can generate both the PFvv and the PFYvv mangled names:

```
#ifdef          __cplusplus
extern  "C" {                               /* C declarations in C++     */
#endif

class CCASD {
public:
    static int lol(in_str*h, char* name, void(*fn)(void), unsigned char p, void *s, unsigned long l);//Will be PFYvv
};

#ifdef          __cplusplus
}                                           /* End of C declarations     */
#endif

class CCASD {
public:
    static int lol(in_str*h, char* name, void(*fn)(void), unsigned char p, void *s, unsigned long l);//Will be PFvv
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, [the ARM ABI is based on the more common Itanium ABI](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0041e/IHI0041E_cppabi.pdf) (with some modifications that are enumerated in the linked document).

So we head [over there](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html)… and discover that [the `Y` comes from the `<function-type>` production](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangle.function-type) of your "pointer to function" type, with the following explanation:

> A "Y" prefix for the bare function type encodes extern "C" in implementations which distinguish between function types with "C" and "C++" language linkage. This affects only type mangling, since extern "C" function objects have unmangled names.

As for whether you have one of those implementations (I mean in general; clearly yours is one of them), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26647735/560648) is worth a read.

Comment: Thanks, you make it seem quite simple but not knowing much about mangling it was hard to search! :)

Comment: Also , it would be useful to have a practical example difference of the 2 possible declarations

Comment: Added in the question a snippet of code to generate both cases!

Comment: @Kons: You're welcome. The only thing I searched for was "ARM ABI" .. the rest was just reading and following clues. People rely too much on "searching" to jump straight to their answer; I really think they should do more _studying_! By taking you through my process, I'd hoped to show the value of that. Also... there's an example in the question I linked you to and suggested reading ;)

Comment: I'm up for all you've written, and although I'm an embedded C engineer I never had to look so closely to C++ mangling.. 
I would have never searched "ARM ABI" :D in the first place!
Thanks again :)