# How can I check whether a function is extern-C?

Tags: c++, reflection, abi, cross-language, extern-c

In C++, can I check whether a certain function has been declared "extern C" or not?

- I don't mind checks restricted to the current translation unit.
- I'd like to check this at compile-time, but if this is somehow possible only at run-time, that's useful too.
- Non-standard, compiler-extension-based solutions are relevant.

Comment: I'm having trouble coming up with a reason to do this. What do you want to use this information for?

Comment: @Kevin: I thought of using something like this in some macro that gets used in unit testing a library which involves exposure of things via shared objects. I can't say I have a compelling use case. But you know what? I'll expand the scope slightly.

Comment: The only thing that extern C changes is the name of the internal symbol used for the function. And a "extern C" function can be C++ code and can access your shared objects just fine.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: You are mistaken in your first sentence. Language linkage is [part of the function type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26647735/1593077). The second sentence is true, but not what I'm asking about here.

Comment: @einpoklum Ok, it changes the type, which is how the compiler knows how the symbol for the function is named. My point was that just because something is `extern "C"` doesn't mean it isn't C++ code. It's required for cross-language calls but is not sufficient to detect cross-language calls (even if you could detect `extern "C"` declarations).

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: Yes, I realize that.