# How to wrap system call with callback parameter into a C++ class?

Tags: c++

I would like to wrap a Linux System Call API (clone) into a C++ class.

However, this API required a function pointer, and it's parameter list is fixed, for instance:

```
typedef int (*callback)(void *);
void system_call(callback f) {
    void *t = nullptr;
    f(t);
}
```

Now, My class like:

```
class Foo {
public:
    void start() {
        // WRONG: cannot pass non-static member function due to pointer `this`
        system_call(this->foo);
    }
private:
    int foo(void *args) {
        f->necessary();
        return 0;
    }
    void necessary() {
        std::cout << "call success!!!" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo obj;
    obj.start();
}
```

So, the important problems are:

1. system_call's parameter are fixed and unchangeable.
2. the method `start()` must be non-static.

I was thinking about this, by using a static member:

```
class Foo {
public:
    void start() {
        auto func = std::bind(foo, std::placeholders::_1, this);
        system_call(func);  // WRONG: cannot convert std::_Bind to a function pointer
    }
private:
    static int foo(void *args, Foo *f) {
        f->necessary();
        return 0;
    }
    void necessary() {
        std::cout << "call success!!!" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

or this, by using lambda with captures:

```
class Foo {
public:
    void start() {
        auto func = [this](void *args) -> int {
            this->necessary();
        };
        system_call(func); // WRONG: cannot convert a lambda with captures to a function pointer
    }
private:
    void necessary() {
        std::cout << "call success!!!" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

They all wrong.

Any solutions to fix this problem?

P.S. I think this is a huge requirements for encapsulation, but here I found some answers are not elegant (they modified the parameter list, not possible for system call):

[how to pass a non static-member function as a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097738/how-to-pass-a-non-static-member-function-as-a-callback)

Comment: What is the "Linux System Call API", in question? This has all the potential of an XY problem. Although there are several classical hacks, to implement class method callbacks, I strongly suspect an XY problem, and there's likely a more appropriate answer for this particular "Linux System Call API", in question.

Comment: Wow, high signal to noise ratio: 11 lines for a 1 line system call.  I recommend you review the [IOCCC](http://www.ioccc.org/) rules.

Comment: You don't need `this` when calling static function, so you don't need `std::bind`

Comment: @ThomasMatthews well, you are right about this, however we are trying to use C++, so we have to warp it into an object. If we straightly use system call, then why we just change to C code in the project?

Comment: Are you making a call to the Internal server or the Linux System Call API means to some external environment procedure call?

Comment: @Drop the idea of using `std::bind` is trying to make `foo`'s parameter list match the `system_call` requirement. However is not working due to the type of `func` is `std::_Bind`

Comment: Do you want to *wrap* the system call or *warp* it?  Or do you want to make a system call into a call (me) back function?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The original requirement all list in this question. I would like to warp the `clone()` system call into one of my class.

Comment: @OuChangkun this idea will not work of course. You need a function with exact same signature. And system calls are all C, and C doesn't have `std::bind` or lambdas.

Comment: @Drop Exactly, that's why I'm turn to here for a help.. Any better solutions?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Have you check my code sample? Pass `this->foo` into `system_call` is my original requirement.

Comment: I'm still having a hard time figuring out why you need a wrap a class around a single statement or function call.  There are solutions for passing pointers to member functions as call-back functions.

Comment: What exactly is this void pointer t supposed to be pointing at? A lot of c-style system calls not only take a pointer to the callback function, but also a pointer that is used as an argument for the callback function as an argument (like `system_call(callback f, void * arg)`) If that is the case, you can essentially pass the this pointer as an argument (with some wrapping and unwrapping)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Passing pointer to member functions never solve this problem, `system_call` execute its function pointer. Member function must adapt `system_call`, not reverse. So, `system_call` execute `f`, `Foo`'s non static-member function `foo` need to be execute. See? Passing `this->foo` to `system_call`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I knew it was an XY problem. I asked specifically which system call in question, and you write that it is `clone()`.

If you [review the documentation of `clone()`](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman2/clone.2.html) you will find that it takes an `arg` parameter, also:

> When the fn(arg) function application returns, the child process
>   termi‐ nates.  The integer returned by fn is  the  exit  code  for 
>   the  child process.   The  child  process may also terminate
>   explicitly by calling exit(2) or after receiving a fatal signal.

So, all that's needed is to pass the static `callback()` function to `clone()`.

Then pass the `this` pointer for `arg`.

Then have your `callback()` invoke the real class method.

```
void callback(void *arg)
{
    reinterpret_cast<Foo *>(arg)->foo();
}
```

Not only that, it is trivial to pass arbitrary parameters, using the single pointer:

1. Define a `struct` that holds any needed parameters in addition to the pointer to the `Foo` class whose method is to be invoked.
2. `new` an instance of the class, put `this` into the pointer, and initialize the parameters to pass.
3. Pass a pointer to this class as the `arg` parameter to `clone()`.
4. Have your callback fetch the `Foo` pointer, and all the parameters from the `struct`, invoke the class method, passing to this method any needed parameters, then `delete` the `new`ed parameter struct.

This is a very common design pattern: a function that takes a callback function pointer will also take an additional, second opaque pointer that gets forwarded to the callback-ed function, which it can use to store whatever ancillary data the callback needs. Such as a pointer to an instance of a class whose method should be invoked. Not structuring a callback mechanism this way is actually a poor programming practice.

Comment: Thank you very much Sam! I leaned a lot through you answer. I was thinking about the args in clone() is an output parameter and useless, I will learn more about C.

Answer (score -1):

**Solution 1**

The simplest work around is to use a non-member function that uses a global variable.

```
// The global variable
Foo* currentFooPtr = NULL;

// The callback function. Define it after the definition of Foo
int foo_callback(void *);
```

And then use `foo_callback` as argument to `system_call` after setting the value of `currentFooPtr`.

```
class Foo {
public:
    void start() {
        currentFooPtr = this;
        system_call(foo_callback);
    }
};

int foo_callback(void *)
{
   // Use currentFooPtr any way you wish to
}
```

Important note for multi-threaded programs (thanks due to @SamVarshavchik):

> This'll work only as long as the application is not multithreaded; or, specifically, it is not possible to execute the system call more than once, concurrently. Otherwise, you'll probably want the call protected by a global mutex.

**Solution 2**

Instead of a global variable and a non-member function, use a `static` member variable and a `static` member function. I think it is better than Solution 1 since it doesn't add a variable or a function to the global scope that are only meant to be used by `Foo`.

```
class Foo {
public:
    void start() {
        currentFooPtr = this;
        system_call(foo_callback);
    }

    static Foo* currentFooPtr;
    static int foo_callback(void*);      
};

Foo* Foo::currentFooPtr = NULL;

int Foo::foo_callback(void *)
{
   // Use currentFooPtr any way you wish to
}
```

Comment: This'll work only as long as the application is not multithreaded; or, specifically, it is not possible to execute the system call more than once, concurrently. Otherwise, you'll probably want the call protected by a global mutex.

Comment: Thanks for your solution! It did solved this problem, however, it not quite elegant. Global variables, which is belongs to C, you know what I mean...

Comment: @OuChangkun Note that technically, in the last example, those are still global function and global variable, but with "elegant" `Foo::` qualifier. And what is not elegant is that now you need to expose all this elegance in the header file (Foo declaration). While if you would go with globals, you could keep them hidden in the .cpp file, so a client wouldn't get a clue about the black magic inside.

Comment: @RSahu Thanks for your updates! Solution 2 makes me feel better, indeed. :) It is an excellent alternative method to avoid function pointer casting.