# Trampolining a non-static C++ member as a registered C callback

Tags: c++, c++11, opengl, callback, glut

I am writing a C++ [freeGlut 3.0.0](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/) application. I am having trouble registering a **generic** callback signature (hopefully a function pointer template argument) with a **non static member function** that matches the signatures of the declared free-glut callbacks.

To this end, with the help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881896/using-a-c-class-member-function-cannot-be-static-as-a-c-callback-function), I put together a [live Coliru working example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9fb9d0532708035d) that demonstrates how to register a C++ non static method as a callback with a C application (in my case the freeGlut library).  A better C interface would allow a caller to specify an optional void* user parameter which would typically be bound to `this` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097738/how-to-pass-a-non-static-member-function-as-a-callback). 
FreeGlut does not allow provide a mechanism to do this in their [callback registration API](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/docs/api.php#GlobalCallback), so it seems that I need to use a trampolining technique that I am not very familiar with - especially when it comes to variadic parameter packs and such type_trait magic.

My cobbled together example uses one specific callback signature `callback_t`.  The place where I need help is to allow a more generic callback templated type - perhaps the trampolining example [live coliru demo](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/docs/api.php#GlobalCallback) could be adapted to make my example more generic but I am not sure how to get this working.  I suspect I need to change the `callback_t` to somehow allow variadic arguments and a templated return type but I don't know how.

```
using callback_t = std::add_pointer<int(const char *, int)>::type;
using MyFTWFunction = std::function<void(unsigned char, int, int)>;

template <MyFTWFunction *callback>
class callback_binder {
public:
    static void trampoline(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
        return (*callback)(key, x, y);
    }
};

// This matches the signature of the callbacks in freeGlut
extern "C" {
    // register the keyboard callback here
    void glutKeyboardFunc(void(*callback)(unsigned char ch, int x, int y)) {
        callback('S', 3, 4);
    }
    // register Reshape callback here
    void glutReshapeFunc(void(*callback)(int, int)) {
        callback(1, 2);
    }
    // register Display callback here
    void glutDisplayFunc(void(*callback)(void)) {
        callback();
    }
}
```

I need help making it more generic such that I can also register other callbacks.