# What is the use of static member functions that are not related / declared inside a class?

Tags: c++

I totally understand the use of static functions that are members of a class. But what might be the probable use of static functions that are not related to any class or defined globally. eg-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
static int func()
{
    cout<<"This is a function";
}

int main()
{
 /*Random code here*/
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `static` at namespace scope denotes [internal linkage](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1358400/636019).

Comment: [static](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/4891/keywords/18689/static#t=201611200648130483261)

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more please. I am a newbie to static functions.

Comment: I prefer using the anonymous namespace for this. Partly because it avoids some of the confusion over `static`.

Comment: [This is a semantic inherited from `C`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684450/what-is-the-difference-between-static-and-extern-in-c).

Comment: `static` is quite a horrible keyword in C++. In a perfect world, you would have different keywords for all its different meanings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This creates a function that's visible only inside that translation unit. A translation unit is basically that source file (after preprocessing, so what was in the headers it included plus what's directly in the file itself).

It's roughly equivalent to putting the function inside an anonymous namespace, but the anonymous namespace is generally considered preferable.

Comment: What is a translation unit ? Can you please elaborate a bit more ?