# Calling a static function with global variables in C

Tags: c, global-variables, static-methods

I have a static function defined in a c file that uses global static variables of the file. If I call the function from another file and I define the same static global variables but with different values, will it use the values from the original file or from the other file?
If not, is there a way to use global parameters in a function I'm calling from different files without receiving them as inputs?

Comment: global *static* variables are file-local... so I guess the answer is "no, it wouldn't", and "no"... and where's the code?

Comment: Furthermore a function with static visibility cannot be called from another file.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684450/what-is-the-difference-between-static-and-extern-in-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use extern to share variables between source files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files)

Comment: "global" and "static" is actually the same thing. Do you mean `static` qualified?

Answer (score 2):

Static variables defined at the outermost level of a source file have **file scope**, i.e.: they are only visible in that file.

As an example, if you have a source file `foo.c`:

```
static int var;
```

and another one `bar.c`:

```
static int var;
```

There are two different copies of a variable with the name `var`. Each copy is only visible in the file in which it is defined.

Comment: Try to avoid naming like this, name them foo_var and bar_var. You will thank yourself when debugging.