# Nested Classes C++ static inner methods (Xml parsing and trying to populate vector with values)

Tags: c++, class, function, methods, nested

So this is what I am trying to accomplish. I am trying to use a sax parser to parse some XML. it looks like I need to call all their methods as statics.  So if I want to pass a value back from say startElement it is static void startElement. Which brings me to my example code. I have been pulling my hair on how to update a value in a Nesting class from a static member function.

I have looked at several things such as defining OuterClass * oc; then trying to reference oc->allRecords, but since it is a static method inside, it fails. I am sure I am doing something wrong architecturally, so any feedback on what would be the right way to do this would be a great help. Thanks.

```
class Attribute {
    string AttributeName;
    string AttributeValue;
};
typedef shared_ptr<Attribute> AttributePtr;

class AttributeSet {
    vector<AttributePtr> Attributes;
};
typedef shared_ptr<AttributeSet> AttributeSetPtr;

class OuterClass {
    public :
    vector<AttributeSetPtr> allRecords;
    class InnerClass {
         public:
         static mymethod1() {
            // I need to be able to set attributes here :
            // This would be the characters method for sax parsing 
            // What is the right way to Attributes.push_back(new Attribute(Name,Value));
         }


         static mymethod2() {
            // I also need to be able to add Records here :
            // This would be the endElement for sax parsing
            //  What is the right way to allRecords.push_back(AttributeSet);
         }
   };

   // EDIT: CALLING CODE GOES HERE (WAS EDITED - SEE BELOW) 
};



// ADDING INFORMATION REGARDING HOW METHOD 1 & 2 are called
xmlSAXHandler saxHandler;
memset(&saxHandler, 0, sizeof(saxHandler));
saxHandler.initialized = XML_SAX2_MAGIC;
...
saxHandler.endElementsNs = &InnerClass::method2;
saxHandler.characters = &InnerClass::method1;
...
InnerClass innerXmlParsingClass
xmlSaxUserParseMemory( &saxHandler, &innerXmlParsingClass, xmlString, xmlString.length());
```

Comment: What sax library do you use? If it doesn't have a user supplied context parameter to store this pointer you can't do this without some ugly hacks (thunks to be specific).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is using an inner class (are you coming from Java?).

I don't know what you believe you are are achieving with an inner class, but it won't work. Don't use inner classes in C++ unless you really know what it does (*for inner classes, protected and private members of the outer classes are seen as if they were public*).

Now, as the solution to your problem, I guess it depends on the implementation you're using (I used once Apache's Xerces SAX, but I know Microsoft offers its own SAX implementation, and that there should be a lot other alternatives, so...)

### Edit

After the comment, I found the following tutorial:

http://www.jamesh.id.au/articles/libxml-sax/libxml-sax.html

I must say that, coming from Java to C++, and using a C API, you have a kind of courage...

:-D

If you are not familiar enough with function pointers, and C in general, using libxml2 will be a challenge. Be sure that in the end, you will understand those notions... Note that C have a way to handle the data that C++, Java or C# developers associate to `this`. The C way is to pass a pointer to your data (the user data) to a function, and when the callback is called, it passes back this pointer, typed as a `void *`. You must then cast it back to its right type, and *voilà*, you have your `this` back.

:-)

Anyway, reading the doc, I see that when you parse the file, you'll call the following C function:

```
int xmlSAXUserParseFile(   xmlSAXHandlerPtr   sax,
                           void *             user_data,
                           const char *       filename);
```

the `user_data` part is the one that interest you because it enables you to have a context. So, wrapping this function in a C++ class, you could have something like:

```
// MySaxBase.hpp
class MySaxBase
{
   public :
       MySaxBase() ;
       int parseFile(const std::string & p_filename) ;
       virtual void startDocument() ;
       virtual void endDocument() ;
   private :
       static void do_startDocument(void *p_user_data) ;
       static void do_endDocument(void *p_user_data) ;
       xmlSAXHandler     m_sax ;
}
```

.

```
// MySaxBase.cpp

extern "C"
{

void do_startDocument(void *p_user_data)
{
   // this static method will convert the p_user_data into
   // the this pointer...
   MySaxBase * saxBase = static_cast<MySaxBase *>(p_user_data) ;
   // ...and call the right virtual method
   saxBase->startDocument() ;
}

void do_endDocument(void *p_user_data)
{
   // this static method will convert the p_user_data into
   // the this pointer...
   MySaxBase * saxBase = static_cast<MySaxBase *>(p_user_data) ;
   // ...and call the right virtual method
   saxBase->endDocument() ;
}

} // extern "C"

MySaxBase::MySaxBase()
{
   // the m_sax structure must be set to zero to NULL all its
   // pointers to functions
   memset(&m_sax, 0, sizeof(xmlSAXHandler)) ;
   // Now, we initialize some pointers to the static method we
   // want to be called
   this->m_sax.startDocument = do_startDocument ;
   this->m_sax.endDocument = do_endDocument ;
}

int MySaxBase::parseFile(const std::string & p_filename)
{
   // the important thing, here, is the this pointer, passed as
   // a user_data parameter
   return xmlSAXUserParseFile(&m_sax, this, p_filename.c_str()) ;
}

void MySaxBase::startDocument()
{
   // The document started. Override this method to
   // actually do something
}

void MySaxBase::endDocument()
{
   // The document ended. Override this method to
   // actually do something
}
```

I did not test this, and I never used libxml2, but I guess the code must be Ok, and this should be enough for you to continue on your own: Just add the methods you want to support, initialize the sax handler with the relevant function pointers, and you'll have your class complete.

The `MySaxBase::startDocument` and `MySaxBase::endDocument` methods are virtual just for you to derive from MySaxBase and then override those methods.

### Edit 2

I'll reproduce here Steve Jessop's excellent comment:

> +1. One tiny quibble - I don't think that `static` member functions are guaranteed by the C++ standard to have C linkage / calling convention, but to use them as a callback from a C API, that's what they need. I don't specifically know what implementations it makes a difference, but for safety `do_startDocument` should be a free function declared with `extern "C"`. On the same subject: a Java programmer may not realise you have make sure that the function can't throw an exception (because C doesn't have them). So you'd normally want to see a `try/catch(...)` in the wrapper function. – [Steve Jessop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13005/steve-jessop)

Following this, and after reading Johannes Schaub - litb (who else?) no less excellent answer at [static vs extern "C"/"C++"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592160/static-vs-extern-c/592205#592205) , I modified the code to make `do_startDocument` and `do_endDocument` real C functions (i.e. wrapped in an extern "C" block). This usually is not important (I never encountered this kind of problem), but, better safe than sorry.

Comment: +1 for the observation that OP might be using the wrong construct to begin with.

Comment: Yes, coming from Java, hence my issues.. Trying to implement sax w/ libxml2

Comment: +1. One tiny quibble - I don't think that `static` member functions are guaranteed by the C++ standard to have C linkage / calling convention, but to use them as a callback from a C API, that's what they need. I don't specifically know what implementations it makes a difference, but for safety `do_startDocument` should be a free function declared with `extern "C"`. On the same subject: a Java programmer may not realise you have make sure that the function can't throw an exception (because C doesn't have them). So you'd normally want to see a `try/catch(...)` in the wrapper function.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: +1 for the comment, which led me to this litb's answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592160/static-vs-extern-c/592205#592205 , and then to the modification of my code. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Your basic problem is that `static` methods are not per-instance, so there is no `this` pointer.  You somehow need to get a `OuterClass*` passed to `mymethod1` and `mymethod2`.

If you show us how `mymethod1` and `mymethod2` are called, we can help you further.

If it's simply called by you someplace where you have a `OuterClass` object, then your solution is simple:

```
class OuterClass
{
// ...
  static void mymethod1(OuterClass* oc)
  {
    oc->all_records.push_back( something );
  }
};

void some_func()
{
  OuterClass oc;
  OuterClass::method1(&oc);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you updated your question here is how you should do this:

```
class OuterClass {
public:
    vector<AttributeSetPtr> allRecords;

    void characters(const xmlChar* ch, int len)
    {
        // do here whatever you want
        allRecords.push_back(bla bla);
    }

    static void static_characters(void* ctx, const xmlChar* ch, int len) {
        // retrieve this pointer from ctx
        static_cast<OuterClass*>(ctx)->characters(ch, len);
    }
};

saxHandler.characters = &OuterClass::static_characters;
...
OuterClass outerClass;
xmlSaxUserParseMemory(&saxHandler, static_cast<void*>(&outerClass), xmlString, xmlString.length());
```