# error: converting from ‘void (FlashWork::*)(int, siginfo_t*, void*)’ to ‘void* (*)(int, siginfo_t*, void*)’

Tags: c++, c, linux, signals

I am a C programmer (on linux), but now I have a project on C++, and have a question.

Here is sample code

```
g_action.sa_sigaction = (void(*)(int,siginfo_t*,void*))&FlashWork::Disconnect_action;
```

When I try to compile this on x86, it works fine, but on arm I get the following error

> error: converting from `void (FlashWork::*)(int, siginfo_t*, void*)` to `void (*)(int, siginfo_t*, void*)`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error message in the header doesn't match the code and the error message in the question text. The header has an extra `*` in the return type of the destination type, `void*` rather than `void`. The question body is the correct function type for sigaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Pointer to members" are not compatible with "pointers to functions", unless it's a `static` member. The reason is that a pointer to member needs an object (a `FlashWork` object) in your case.

Comment: Actually even if it's `static` it still won't have `extern "C"` linkage required for sa_sigation. Most implementations allow it, but it's not mandated.

Comment: @awoodland, isn't `extern "C"` related to name-mangling? How is that a problem with function pointers (in which you have the function's address, and not the name anymore)

Comment: @Shahbaz: Theoretically, it can also affect calling conventions, and it _is_ considered in overload resolution. Which is why C++ defines two overloads of `qsort`.

Comment: @Shahbaz - it's not just name mangling, they're still distinct types in theory. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068022/in-c-is-it-safe-portable-to-use-static-member-function-pointer-for-c-api-call and http://stackoverflow.com/a/592205/168175

Comment: Good to know, I had never though about it

Answer (score 1):

Your function is a member function that returns a `void`. It should be a non-member function (or a static member function) that returns a `void *`.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the fact the return value of the functions are different, you should know that in C++, when you have a member function (**which is not static**):

```
void (FlashWork::*)(int, siginfo_t*, void*)
```

The real signature (the one a C programmer likes to see) is this:

```
void (*)(FlashWork *, int, siginfo_t *, void *)
```

That `FlashWork *` parameter is a hidden pointer which can be referred to by `this`.

Therefore,

```
void (FlashWork::*)(int, siginfo_t*, void*)
```

and

```
void (*)(int, siginfo_t*, void*)
```

have different number of arguments.

Comment: Putting the "extra parameter" first might be misleading. You can't convert `&FlashWork::Disconnnect_action` to `void (*)(FlashWork *, int, siginfo_t *, void *)` either, so that's not the "real" signature. On any given implementation the calling convention for member functions may or may not look the same as if they were free functions with `this` passed as the first parameter.

Comment: @SteveJessop, right. I just wanted to point out that `this` is also a parameter. I always thought it would be the first parameter though. Good to know.

Comment: On Windows/x86 for example, all parameters of non-member calls are passed on the stack (unless the fastcall convention is used, but for public API calls it isn't). `this` is passed in the register ECX, as is the first parameter when using fastcall. But in thiscall all (other) parameters are on the stack, whereas in fastcall the second parameter goes in EDX. So the calling convention with `this` isn't the same as adding it as the first parameter to either of the other two calling conventions.