# Exit Code -11 'Segmentation Fault' executing pthread_create

Tags: qt, pthreads, segmentation-fault, argument-passing, ros

I'm trying to create a new thread by executing pthread_create with a single argument.

```
void P2FPanel::startRecording()
{
  qDebug() << "Start recording...";
  qDebug() << "_bag_list: " << _bag_list->size();
  pthread_create(&_playBags_t, NULL, playBags, _bag_list);
  qDebug() << ".... Started";
}
```

This method is triggered by a button and creates the pthread.
Here the code already exits with error -11 (I think it's segmentation fault).
The debug lines show that _bag_list is not empty.

```
void* P2FPanel::*playBags(void* arg0)
{
  qDebug() << "Play Bags from _bag_list...";
  QList<BagRef*> *bag_list = (QList<BagRef*>*) arg0;
  qDebug() << "Play " << QString("%1").arg(bag_list->size()) << " Bags";
  //Do stuff
  qDebug() << "Finished playing";
  return 0;
}
```

This method should run in a new thread.

```
class P2FPanel: public rviz::Panel
{

  private Q_SLOTS:
    void startRecording();

  private:
    QList<BagRef*> *_bag_list;
    void* (*playBags)(void* arg0);
    pthread_t _playBags_t;

};
```

The header file.

Where is the error coming from?
Is the declaration of the threaded method correct?

Thanks in advance, best regards,
Josch

Comment: Is there any particular reason for not using QThread?

Comment: I didn't know QThreads exist. Thanks for the hint, they're even more easy to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I remember, you cannot pass class-methods into pthreads.
Consider: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86046/best-way-to-start-a-thread-as-a-member-of-a-c-class) and [that](http://blog.emptycrate.com/node/270).
You should use static methods.

Comment: You're welcome :) I once had this issue, too and it took me some time!